# kaggleword2vec utility not found

Tags: python, scikit-learn, word2vec

I'm trying to follow along with some tutorials to complete some projects/competitions but I can't seem to find "kaggleword2vec"; any suggestions?

```
import os 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from KaggleWord2VecUtility import KaggleWord2VecUtility
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jordanXXX/Documents/NLP/sentimentanalysis9", line 4, in <module>
    from KaggleWord2VecUtility import KaggleWord2VecUtility
ImportError: No module named KaggleWord2VecUtility
```

Where can I find the KaggleWord2VecUtility? I have Word2Vec and a bunch of other toolkits I've been using but this one in particular isn't recognized. I'd like to continue following the tutorials but can't seem to without this module.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get everything you need here https://github.com/wendykan/DeepLearningMovies

Comment: @ballpointpen thanks for sharing, but i'm not sure how to download that. i've seen that page before but i'm not sure what exactly to do :/

Comment: You can just open each file and manually download if you don't want to use git.

Comment: @ballpointpen i'm using a mac with brew and can use **brew install** or **pip install** or **easy_install** but can probably figure out how to download them.